# For some products, in default scope, only root category is chooseable?

Tags: magento

just stumbled across a weird Magento problem.

Some products in the backend only has "root" as a chooseable category in the categories tab...   but all categories appear if i choose a storefront as scoope.

While some other products has the whole tree chooseable in the default scope.

Index & cache has been reset.

Any clues? Please :)

Comment: Might be a duplicate of this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5192396/magento-doesnt-show-all-the-categories-in-admin/31665603#31665603

Answer (score 0):

you can find the solution here:
http://zaclee.net/magento/errors-magento/magento-product-edit-only-shows-default-category

Greetz!

Answer (score 0):

Theres another solution in comments there. I changed it to find the categories with inconsistent children count without modifying them in the first place:

```
select
  entity_id,
  children_count,
   (select (SELECT count(*) from catalog_category_entity u1 
            where u1.path REGEXP CONCAT('^',u2.path,'/[[:digit:]]+$')) 
    from catalog_category_entity u2 
    where u2.path = w1.path) 
  as actual_children_count
from catalog_category_entity w1
having children_count != actual_children_count
```

After you examine the offending records, run the update by Tim Schmidt:

```
CREATE TABLE catalog_category_entity_test AS SELECT * FROM catalog_category_entity;

UPDATE catalog_category_entity w1 
SET children_count = (
  select (SELECT count(*) from catalog_category_entity_test u1 
          where u1.path REGEXP CONCAT('^',u2.path,'/[[:digit:]]+$')) 
  from catalog_category_entity_test u2 where u2.path = w1.path)

DROP TABLE catalog_category_entity_test;
```